# roscore is not working and cant install pip or rospkg?

Tags: ros, python, ros-hydro, ros-fuerte, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I has frute then I remove it and I downloaded hydro. I followed the steps until I reached to this step:

```
sudo rosdep init
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 3, in <module>
from rosdep2.main import rosdep_main
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
from .installers import InstallerContext, Installer, \
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/installers.py", line 35, in <module>
from rospkg.os_detect import OsDetect
ImportError: No module named rospkg.os_detect
```

Then I looked for a solution and I did the following:

```
pip install -U rospkg
```

I got the following error :

```
Downloading/unpacking rospkg
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement rospkg
No distributions at all found for rospkg
Storing complete log in /home/asctec/.pip/pip.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 116, in main
return command.main(initial_args, args[1:], options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 147, in main
 log_fp = open_logfile(log_fn, 'w')
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 176, in open_logfile
 log_fp = open(filename, mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/asctec/.pip/pip.log'
```

Also I tried:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

and I got the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip
Downloading pip-1.5.6.tar.gz (938Kb): 40Kb downloaded  
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 955, in prepare_files
 self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1072, in unpack_url
 return unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, only_download)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 441, in unpack_http_url
 download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 366, in _download_url
 chunk = resp.read(4096)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
 data = self._sock.recv(left)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 561, in read
 s = self.fp.read(amt)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
 data = self._sock.recv(left)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
 return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
  return self._sslobj.read(len)
  SSLError: The read operation timed out
 Storing complete log in /home/asctec/.pip/pip.log
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
  load_entry_point('pip==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 116, in main
 return command.main(initial_args, args[1:], options)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 147, in main
 log_fp = open_logfile(log_fn, 'w')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 176, in open_logfile
log_fp = open(filename, mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/asctec/.pip/pip.log'
```

What should I do exactly to make **roscore** working because it is not working ??????????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193189/roscore-is-not-working-and-cant-install-pip-or-rospkg-??/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-22**:
try `sudo easy_install rospkg`

**Comment by [Vova Niu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19788/vova-niu/) on 2014-09-22**:
what version of Ubuntu are you using?

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-09**:
@Vova Niu
ubuntu 12.04

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-09**:
@bvbdort I solve it using the command of re-install. I will post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem using the following command

sudo apt-get re-install python-rosdep

---

Originally posted by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) with karma: 275 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) on 2019-08-01**:
In my case it did not work, but I used:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-rosdep
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do **not** use pip to install Python package on Ubuntu. Instead remove these packages installed via pip and install them using Debian packages.

Please use the search to find numerous similar questions regarding the same topic.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1